# iOS10 Speech Recognition "Listening" sound effect

Tags: ios, iphone, speech-recognition

I am doing live speech recognition with the new iOS10 framework. I use `AVCaptureSession` to get to audio.

I have a "listening" beep sound to notify the user he can begin talking. The best way to put that sound is at the 1st call to `captureOutput(:didOutputSampleBuffer..)`, but if I try to play a sound after starting the session the sound just won't play. And no error is thrown.. it just silently fail to play...

What I tried:

- Playing through a system sound (`AudioServicesPlaySystemSound...()`)
- Play an asset with `AVPlayer`
- Also tried both above solutions async/sync on main queue

It seems like regardless of what I am doing, it is impossible to trigger playing any kind of audio after triggering the recognition (not sure if it's specifically the `AVCaptureSession` or the `SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest` / `SFSpeechRecognitionTask`...)

Any ideas? [Apple even recommends playing a "listening" sound effect](https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech) (and do it themselves with Siri) but I couldn't find any reference/example showing how to actually do it... (their "[SpeakToMe](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SpeakToMe)" example doesn't play sound)

- I can play the sound before triggering the session, and it does work (when starting the session at the completion of playing the sound) but sometimes theres a lag in actually staring the recognition (mostly when using BT headphones and switching from a different AudioSession category - for which I do not have a completion event...) - because of that I need a way to play the sound when the recording actually starts, and not before it triggers and cross fingers it won't lag starting it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, apparently there are a bunch of "rules" one must follow in order to successfully begin a speech recognition session and play a "listening" effect only when (after) the recognition **really** began.

1. The session setup & triggering must be called on main queue. So:

   ```
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       speechRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
       task = recognizer.recognitionTask(with: speechRequest, delegate: self)
       capture = AVCaptureSession()
       //.....
       shouldHandleRecordingBegan = true
       capture?.startRunning()
   }
   ```
2. The "listening" effect should be player via `AVPlayer`, not as a system sound.
3. The safest place to know we are **definitely** recording, is in the delegate call of `AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`, when we get our first sampleBuffer callback:

   ```
   func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

       //only once per recognition session
       if shouldHandleRecordingBegan {
           shouldHandleRecordingBegan = false

           player = AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "listening", withExtension: "aiff")!)
           player.play()            

           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               //call delegate/handler closure/post notification etc...
           }
       }

       // append buffer to speech recognition
       speechRequest?.appendAudioSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
   }
   ```
4. End of recognition effect is hell of a lot easier:

   ```
   var ended = false

   if task?.state == .running || task?.state == .starting {
       task?.finish() // or task?.cancel() to cancel and not get results.
       ended = true
   }

   if true == capture?.isRunning {
       capture?.stopRunning()
   }

   if ended {
       player = AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "done", withExtension: "aiff")!)
       player.play()
   }
   ```